# error : connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, econnrefused

I am running a node app with mysql as my database(also using sequelize as ORM). Whenever I run the "app.js" file with "node" command, I get an error:

{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }

```
my code in the app.js file:

var  mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "openshare"
});

connection.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("no errors");
  }
});
```

Comment: Nothing was listening at 127.0.0.1:3306. MySQL wasn't running there, or running on a different port.

Comment: Thanks that fixes it, but after that I get another error with the same code running: { [Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true }

Comment: So you used an invalid username or password, or that user didn't have 'localhost ' access.

Comment: for root user mysql default password is empty string

Comment: @Adiii Not in my experience. Every time I've installed it I've been asked to *specify* a root password.

Comment: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,140320,140324

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for help guys, your comments lead me towards the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably should have mentioned before hand, but I am using cloud9 to for my node environment. Cloud9 has some things setup for you already:

1. Your "host" to connect to will just be "localhost".
2. "user" will be your cloud9 username.
3. "password will be left blank.
4. "database" will be "c9"

```js
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "seth40047",
  password: "",
  database: "c9"
});
```

https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mysql/1718
This article is very helpful for anyone who is also having troubles setting up MySql on a cloud9 node environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to connect node to a database in Cloud9. he fix was to

**run the database and node in the same Cloud9 workspace.**

Though this might be obvious to more experienced coders, I wrongly thought that I had the two workspaces communicating.